# Unable to compile on Windows 10 using CMake and Visual Studio 2019 because it can't find MSBuild nor the compiler

Tags: c, cmake, msbuild

I am trying to compile the dlib software on Windows 10. I don't have experience compiling C software so I follow the instructions. It says I need to use CMake and use a C compiler for it.

When I try to install it, I get an error which basically says:

```
Failed to run MSBuild command:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual         
Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
```

But the file "MSBuild.exe" is there, and I also added the bin folder on Path, but Cmake continue to fail trying to run the MSBuild command.

This happens when I try to install using the python package from the dlib website.

And if I try to compile it myself using the source files from their website, I get the error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I am trying to build using the command: `cmake ..`, but it does not work. I even tried to specify the generator using the command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..` without success.

I would think that Visual Studio was the compiler, so I don't understand this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to launch your commands from the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for Vs 2019" prompt ?
That prompt launches a script that sets up your environment, including the location of your compiler.